# Firefox Crashes at launch on 17.10 (Lubuntu and Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, firefox, 17.10, crash

Very old Shuttle PC with an AMD Athlon XP 1800, 2GB RAM. I've installed Xubuntu 17.04, 17.10 and Lubuntu 17.10. On all when I launch Firefox I immediately get a crash report.

report includes:

```
Build ID 20171227151402
releasechannel: release
safemode: 0
threadIdNameMapping: 5585:"Gecko_IOThread",5586:"Timer",5587:"Link Monitor", 5588:"Socket Thread",5589:"JS Watchdog",
Throttleable: 1
UptimeTS: 1.063488
Version: 57.0.3
```

I've removed and reinstalled Firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the crash report include anything else ? The info you posted does not seem very relevant - it should say _why_ it crashed.

Comment: just my info, install time, product ID, seconds since last crash. Since I have to type it out, I only picked the parts that I thought might be helpful at all. I expected a little more too. At the end it says, "This report also contains technical info about the state of the application when it crashed." However, I don't see any way to gather that info.

Comment: See [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-crashes-asking-support) - does it start in safe mode ? You can start in safe mode by opening a terminal and typing  `firefox --safe-mode`. If not, you can get the techincal info by opening the newest file in `~/.mozilla/firefox/Crash Reports/submitted/` - it's a hidden directory - Ctrl + H should show it in the file manager.

Comment: Safe mode has same issue: crash reporter pops up immediately.

Comment: The crash reports aren't helpful as far as I can tell. The entire contents of LastCrash is`1514998099`, in the Submitted folder there are a few crash files, complete content is `Crash ID: bp-e392caa3-e254-4289-9c55-b1ca30180103`

Comment: Turns out Chromium crashes and so far I can't get Opera to open at all. Chromium takes about 3 minutes, then a crash reporter pops up and disappears after about 1 second.

Comment: there's something bigger going on. opera crashes too. I try to launch it and about 4 minutes later I get a crash report. When i click "more Details" the crash reporter crashes.

Comment: If this used to work I recommend a [package sanity check](/a/57728/175814). If that doesn't turn up anything, try a different graphics driver.

Comment: Newly imaged machine and new machine to me. Trying to set this up for a client. Thank you for your help. I'll see about any driver updates and if that doesn't do it, it's not worth spending time and money on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athlon XP doesn't support the SSE2 instruction set.  Firefox made SSE2 mandatory after v48.0.2. You would think the install would detect the processor type and inform the user before aborting and the latest compatible browsers for these older processors would be offered in the repositories, but No. The only Firefox in the repository is a later version that won't run on Pentium III and Athlon XP. You have to download v48.0.2 from somewhere.  Chrome doesn't work, either. So your only clue is a crash during install or 1st run.